# Разный результат вследствие window.onload

Tags: javascript

Недавно начал знакомство с canvas и javascript, сразу решил сделать попробовать сделать арканоид и сразу столкнулся с проблемой, при реализации функции заполнения поля блоков, всегда выходит разный результат то 3 столбца блоков,то 4 то вообще ни одного, как я догадываюсь, связано это с разным временем загрузки страницы...но как это победить я не знаю, самое главное пробовал отключать функции, следующие после функции заполнения, это не помогло.
Заранее спасибо

```js
window.onload = function() 
{
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black'; //выбираем цвет заливки и заливаем поле "canvasa" пунктом ниже
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
  var intervalHandle1 = setTimeout(makefield,100); // вызов функции выстраивания поля из рандомных блоков (фруктов) только один раз, при загрузке
  var intervalHandle2 = setInterval(plate, 500); // тарелка, отбивающая
}
 
 
 
// game main loop
function loop()
{
  // logic
  plate();
  //setTimeout(function() {cooldown = false;}, 500);
  
}
 
function plate() //создаем саму "тарелку" арканоида
        {
        // Создаем объект изображения
        var img = new Image();
        // Загружаем файл изображения
        img.src = 'img/plate.png';
        // Привязываем функцию к событию onload
        // Это указывает браузеру, что делать, когда изображение загружено
        img.onload = function() 
            {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 550, 650);
            };
        }
 
        
        
function sleep(ms) 
{
    ms += new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date() < ms){}
} 
 
 
var blocks = //создаем массив из функций блоков заполнения
[
 
 
 function plum(xpp,ypp) //создаем блок заполнения "слива"
    {
 
    var plum = new Image();
    // Загружаем файл изображения
    plum.src = 'img/plum.png';
    // Привязываем функцию к событию onload
    // Это указывает браузеру, что делать, когда изображение загружено
    plum.onload = function() 
    {
    ctx.drawImage(plum, xpp, ypp);
    };
 
    },
 
 
 
 function orange(xpp,ypp) //создаем блок заполнения "апельсин"
    {
    var orange = new Image();
    // Загружаем файл изображения
    orange.src = 'img/orange1.png';
    // Привязываем функцию к событию onload
    // Это указывает браузеру, что делать, когда изображение загружено
    orange.onload = function() 
    {
    ctx.drawImage(orange, xpp, ypp);
    };
    },
 
 
 function apple(xpp,ypp) //создаем блок заполнения "яблоко"
    {
    var apple = new Image();
    // Загружаем файл изображения
    apple.src = 'img/apple.png';
    // Привязываем функцию к событию onload
    // Это указывает браузеру, что делать, когда изображение загружено
    apple.onload = function() 
    {
    ctx.drawImage(apple, xpp, ypp);
    };
    }
 
]
 
var min1 = 0, max1 = 500;
var xp;
function getRandomInt1(min1, max1)
{
  return xp = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max1 - min1 + 1)) + min1;
}
 
 
var min2 = 0, max2 = 500;
var yp;
function getRandomInt2(min2, max2)
{
  return  yp = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max2 - min2 + 1)) + min2;
}
 
 
 
function randomblock(min, max) //генерирует значение случайного блока для заполнения в поле
{
    min = 0;
    max = 3;
    rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
    return rand = Math.round(rand);
    
}
 
 
 
 
function makefield() //функция создания поля блоков случайного заполнения 
{
  //getRandomInt1(0,300);
  //getRandomInt2(0,300);
  //создаем цикл заполнения canvasa блоками
  var i;
  for (i=0; i<100; i++)
  {
     blocks[randomblock()](i*45,30);
     blocks[randomblock()](i*45,75);
     blocks[randomblock()](i*45,120);
     blocks[randomblock()](i*45,165);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: сделайте работающий пример

Comment: ну так файлы надо подгружать тогда, а они локальные.. здесь практически весь код, кроме html..